# How to iterate through only ONE value in JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl

```
<c:forEach varStatus="status" var="friends" items="${profile.friends}">
    <c:if test="${friends.selectedCount != -1}">
        <th id="closeFriends" style="text-align:center;"></th>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

I don't want to loop through all friends, I just want to loop through ONE friend and check their selected count and display my th off of that. How do I do that?

Comment: Don't loop? Only send the friend in question to the view layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is badly formulated but the concrete functional requirement is understood. You basically want the EL equivalent of the following plain Java equivalent:

```java
if (profile.getFriends().stream().anyMatch(f -> f.getSelectedCount() != -1)) {
    // ...
}
```

This very functionality is also [readily available](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/expression-language/4.0/jakarta-expression-language-spec-4.0.html#stream-and-pipeline) in EL since EL version 3.0 (Java EE 7 / Servlet 3.1). So this should do it for you:

```xml
<c:if test="${profile.friends.stream().anyMatch(f -> f.selectedCount != -1).orElse(false)}">
    <th id="closeFriends" style="text-align:center;"></th>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately getting Cannot convert [org.apache.el.stream.Optional@74b9709b] of type [class org.apache.el.stream.Optional] to [class java.lang.Boolean]